# Jmeter : Summary report : Throughput

Tags: jmeter

is the total throughput shown in last row in Summary Report correct ? I m using Jmeter 2.11

I find it difficult to match the displayed figure by manipulation.

I followed the formula (x/sec) : Number of request / Total response time required (in sec)
Or 1/Avg total response time (sec).

for example : 50 request taking avg response time as 2000 ms each then throughput = 50/(50*2) = 0.5/sec
But Jmeter shows different value than 0.5/sec or 30/min

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also having similar assumption. But this is the formula for calculating throughput.

```
 endTime = lastSampleStartTime + lastSampleLoadTime
 startTime = firstSampleStartTime
 converstion = unit time conversion value

 Throughput = Numrequests / ((endTime - startTime)*conversion)
```

(I got this few months back from the below answer)
[Calculating throughput from Jmeter jtl log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127018/calculating-throughput-from-jmeter-jtl-log-file)

Comment: Refer to JMeter Glossary https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html

It says: The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).